# Unexpected Token Illegal (This isn't a inverted comma issue, its something else)

Tags: javascript, date, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I wrote this syntax after defining the variables and it was perfectly fine.

```
while (v.hasNext()) {
    rs = v.next();
    var c = db.ufcards_click_tracking.find({
        "cardId": rs.cardId
    }).count();
};
```

But when I added another condition to my query, it kept returning this error.

```
while (v.hasNext()) {
    rs = v.next();
    var c = db.ufcards_click_tracking.find({
        "cardId": rs.cardId,
        "cardClickedTime": {
            "$gte": new Date(2015-06-25T00:00:00.000Z)
        }
    }).count();
};
```

I'm going crazy! Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the parameter of [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in quotes:

```
"$gte": new Date("2015-06-25T00:00:00.000Z")
```

Note following in Documentation.

*dateString*:

> **String** value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).